# CSS: double border on td appearing as single border

Tags: html, css, border

I've got an HTML table, `#ols_tbl`, and I'm trying to get a double border along the bottom of a few specific td's of `class="td_double"`.

```
#ols_tbl {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#ols_tbl .td_double {    
    border-bottom: double;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;    
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

I can only get a single line however, any reason why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the `border-width`. Usually you would need `3px`. One pixel for each of the borders, plus one pixel space for the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Your border isn't visibly doubled because it only has 1px width. You can't visibly distinguish between two 1px lines when they are confined within a 1px space. At minimum you'll have to change the width to 3px:

```css
#ols_tbl .td_double {    
    border-bottom-color: #000000;    
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
```

Or simply:

```css
#ols_tbl .td_double {    
    border-bottom: 3px double #000;
}
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/59RjL/1) demonstrating this.